# Laravel - Laratrust - rename permissions name

Tags: php, laravel, web

```
Laravel Version: 7.6.2
Laratrust Version: 5.2.8
```

I have a **Laravel 7.6** project and I use **Laratrust** for user roles and permissions. In my project, When i renamed permission **name** for example from **`management.dashboard.index`** to **`management-dashboard-index`**, but my web application not be loaded (It does not display an error).
Although I have cleared all the caches with **`php artisan cache:clear`**.

aside menu view :

```
@if ($user->can('management-dashboard-index'))
            <li class="kt-menu__section ">
                <h4 class="kt-menu__section-text">مدیریت</h4>
                <i class="kt-menu__section-icon flaticon-more-v2"></i>
            </li>

            <li class="kt-menu__item  kt-menu__item--submenu {!! (Request::is('management/panel/users*')) || (Request::is('management/panel/roles*')) || (Request::is('management/panel/permissions*'))  ? 'kt-menu__item--open kt-menu__item--here' : '' !!}" aria-haspopup="true" data-ktmenu-submenu-toggle="hover">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="kt-menu__link kt-menu__toggle">
                    <span class="kt-menu__link-icon">
                        <i class="la la-users"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="kt-menu__link-text">کاربران</span>
                    <i class="kt-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="kt-menu__submenu ">
                    <span class="kt-menu__arrow"></span>
                    <ul class="kt-menu__subnav">

                        @if ($user->can('management.users.index'))
                        <li class="kt-menu__item {!! Request::is('management/panel/users*') ? 'kt-menu__item--active' : '' !!}" aria-haspopup="true">
                            <a href="{{ route('management.users.index') }}" class="kt-menu__link ">
                                <i class="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--dot">
                                    <span></span>
                                </i>
                                <span class="kt-menu__link-text">لیست کاربران</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        @endif

                        @if ($user->can('management.permissions.index'))
                        <li class="kt-menu__item {!! Request::is('management/panel/permissions*') ? 'kt-menu__item--active' : '' !!}" aria-haspopup="true">
                            <a href="{{ route('management.permissions.index') }}" class="kt-menu__link ">
                                <i class="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--dot">
                                    <span></span>
                                </i>
                                <span class="kt-menu__link-text">پرمیشن ها</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        @endif

                        @if ($user->can('management.roles.index'))
                            <li class="kt-menu__item {!! Request::is('management/panel/roles*') ? 'kt-menu__item--active' : '' !!}" aria-haspopup="true">
                                <a href="{{ route('management.roles.index') }}" class="kt-menu__link ">
                                    <i class="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--dot">
                                        <span></span>
                                    </i>
                                <span class="kt-menu__link-text">سطوح دسترسی</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        @endif

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            @endif
```

i get this message **شما سطح دسترسی لازم را برای دیدن این صفحه ندارید**

Comment: It is quite clear !!!

Comment: Yes, but it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the output of this part of your code `$user->can('management-dashboard-index')`

I think the answer will find if continue digging here.

start by seeing the result of `{{  $user->can('management-dashboard-index') }}`

Comment: the result is "1"

Comment: and still that if statement doesn't run and you got the "شما سطح دسترسی لازم را برای دیدن این صفحه ندارید" msg?